# Is there a way for some components to see an element and some dont when using @Input?

Tags: angular, primeng

I have this table component and this is its HTML.

```
<p-table 
#dt class="withHighlight" 
[columns]="jobCols" 
[value]="jobList" 
dataKey="id" 
selectionMode="single"
[paginator]="jobList.length > 10" 
[rows]="5"
editMode="row">
<ng-template pTemplate="caption">
   <div style="text-align: left">
      <i class="fa fa-search" style="margin:4px 4px 0 0"></i>
      <input type="text" pInputText size="30" (input)="dt.filterGlobal($event.target.value, 'contains')">
   </div>
</ng-template>
<ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
   <tr>
      <th *ngFor="let col of columns" [pSortableColumn]="col.field">
      {{col.header}}
      <p-sortIcon [field]="col.field" ariaLabel="Activate to sort"
         ariaLabelDesc="Activate to sort in descending order" ariaLabelAsc="Activate to sort in ascending order">
      </p-sortIcon>
      </th>
      <!-- <th *ngIf="isReport">Progress bar</th> -->
      <th style="width:7em">Actions</th>
   </tr>
</ng-template>
<ng-template pTemplate="emptymessage" let-columns>
   <tr>
      <td>No data found.</td>
      <td *ngFor="let col of columns"></td>
   </tr>
</ng-template>
<td>
   {{rowData.configuration_title}}
</td>
<td>
   <app-progress-bar [progressBarOptions]="progressBarOptions">
   </app-progress-bar>
</td>
</tr>
</ng-template>
</p-table>
```

In this table component i made a small shared component called app-progress-bar, the table component itself is a shared component and is currently being used by 3 other components like this:

```
<app-table 
[jobTitle]="jobTitle"
[objectTitle]="objectTitle"
[jobList]="loadJobResponseModel" 
[objectList]="loadJobObjects"
[objectCols]="objectCols"
[jobCols]="jobCols"
[progressBarOptions]="progressBarOptions"
>
</app-table>
```

I've tried doing this with *ngIf like this:

```
<td *ngIf="showProgressBar">
   <app-progress-bar [progressBarOptions]="progressBarOptions">
   </app-progress-bar>
</td>
```

and it works but i feel like that my shared component loses its meaning if i put *ngIf inside it.

I would like to use this progress component only in 1 of those 3 components but not in other ones, and since im using the table components html in all of the 3 components how can i tell the table component not to show the progress bar without using ngIf?

Sorry in advance if i didnt explain well or if i did something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can use your progress bar as entry component and render it from the component you want

https://angular.io/guide/entry-components

This way you dont need to declare the component in your template and you can instantiate the progress bar from your controller

Comment: I havent used entry components ill do some research on them and see if it helps, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If progress bar has to be a part of the table component, you will need some kind of input to the child component to add or remove progress bar. What you are doing is correct and I don't believe it loses it's meaning, just makes your child component more dynamic.

If you don't want every other component to send [showProgressBar]="false" as an input, you can make the input optional.

```
@Input() showPorgressBar?: boolean;
```

Now you need to send the showPorgressBar as input only if you are interested in progress bar.

Comment: I've done this but if i start using my table component in even more other components than i am currently using then i have to keep adding ngIfs all the time on every thing i add in the table. If i add something else similar to progress bar that i want to use only in 1 component then i got to use ngIf again, maybe my table component html needs to be refactored somehow to handle these things im not sure.

Comment: Mostly it depends on your use case, but if you are going to render multiple components in future, may be you can use ngFor, and send a list of components and load them dynamically. https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

Comment: i think i will have to use something like that, i will have to do some research or some tutorials since i've never done that. Thank you for answering